# Keep local variables in scope when extending a method

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have a class `TT` inheriting from a class `T` and extending the behaviour of one of its methods, like so:

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self, p, b):
        self.p = p
        self.b = b
        self.fun()
        
    def fun(self):
        a = self.p + self.b
        print(a)
        

class TT(T):
    def __init__(self, p, b):
        super().__init__(p, b)
        
    def fun(self):
        super().fun()
        c = self.p*self.b
        print(c)
```

What I'd like to have is `TT.fun` relying on variables defined in `T.fun`, `a` in this example. The two obvious things that came to mind are to make `T.fun` return `a`, or to make `a` an instance variable, but I don't find either satisfactory. Is there a way for `TT.fun` to share the scope of the method it extends?

---

EDIT

Thanks for the answers.

To expand on my use case, my derived classes run some sort of optimisation of a vector against a dataset. The parent class is here to suggest a common, coherent interface to the different optimisations.
In a class' function to be optimised, some steps (depending on the current state of the vector) are shared by all the subclasses, which is why I figured I'd put it in a parent method. And as Lagerbaer suggests, they were already run in the equivalent of a "private" `compute_a()` method; what I had in mind was to call this method to bring the results to scope in the parent class, so I wouldn't have to do it in individual subclasses. Turns out, given the small number of subclasses I'm dealing with, duplicating a few lines of code may be the simplest thing to do here.

As to Nathaniel Ford's suggestions, this is why I don't find my initial solutions to be satisfactory:

- I don't need this value once the optimisation has been run, and it changes at every optimisation step, that's why I don't think it makes sense to save it as an instance variable.
- Returning the value would lead to the extended method behaving differently as its parent (in a signature sense).
- I don't want anything lingering in a global scope.

As you pointed out, my thinking was not encapsulation-friendly; such a reminder is good to have occasionally!

Comment: "Is there a way for TT.fun to share the scope of the method it extends?" no, no there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straightforward non-hacky way. (And I don't even know if there *is* a hacky way).

What you propose violates the encapsulation principle. A class hides its nitty gritty dirty internals and only exposes a neat interface with promised behavior.

Inheritance is not a mechanism to violate this principle.

In your concrete example, the issue comes from a bad interface design of `T`. If `T` had a method `compute_a()` that would return `self.p + self.b` then in your inherited class you can of course call `self.compute_a()`.

But only do this if `a` is more than a mere internal implementation detail!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is 'no', in particular because the fact a sub-class has a function named the same as one in the parent class does not mean those functions share anything. When you call `super().fun()`, you're calling `fun()` on the parent class, but this is the same as calling `fun()` on a completely unrelated class - except insofar as the parent class is sharing it's state (instance variables).

Therefore, the only way for the sub-class instance to access computation occurring in the parent class instance's function is via normal patterns:

- Saving the result to the instance's state (instance variables).
- Returning the value, such that `super().fun()` becomes `a = super().fun()`
- Saving to to some other more-global-scope value (not recommended).

When you say 'neither way is satisfactory', you should probably dig a little deeper and examine why that is. There are alternatives, such as private methods, that could resolve what seems to be a messy situation in a clean manner. That said, your example doesn't demonstrate why it is `fun()` is even being over-ridden, or what you hope to accomplish by sharing scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a value from `fun()` in the parent class and then assign the returned value to a variable inside the child method. This certainly works but I don't think it's a good design:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, p, b):
        self.p = p
        self.b = b
        self.fun()
        
    def fun(self):
        a = self.p + self.b
        return a
        

class TT(T):
    def __init__(self, p, b):
        super().__init__(p, b)
        
    def fun(self):
        a = super().fun()
        c = self.p * self.b * a
        return c

t = T(2, 3)
tt = TT(2, 3)
print(t.fun())   # >> 5
print(tt.fun())  # >> 30
```

Comment: One important note here is that while you can do this, you should be sure that what is being returned from `T.fun()` is the same type as `TT.fun()`. If `a` and `c` mean different things, stuff will get pretty confusing.